# How to get debugger (LLDB) to work in Codelite. (Mac)

Tags: macos, debugging, lldb

I had this issue from the beginning when i got Codelite. I could not debug from the start. I use Codelite 12.0

> Failed to locate gdb! at 'gdb'

it says when i,m trying to debug. I was searching for a solution and the ordinary tip is to use the LLDB debuger for Mac OS. In the project settings you can choose debugger but i cant see any other option than gdb and as i understand you should be able to choose LLDB debugger there.

How do i get the debugger to work? I really need it to solve some issues with some code..

Answer (score 0):

Under Settings-> General -> Debugger change 'GDB debugger' to 'LLDB Debugger'. I guess it's a bug that this is not adapted to the mac environment.